# How to do grouping in react-admin DataGrid

Tags: react-admin

Is there a way to do grouping in react-admin DataGrid component? See example below

[DataGrid with Grouping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppk5J.png)

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "grouping"? Is it JavaScript and React? Then add the corresponding tags please.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. There is no core component to do that. But you can write your own component to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is to create a specific query that returns the data already grouped, and then use the approach in the demo: https://marmelab.com/react-admin-demo/#/invoices to display the details of each grouped row in a custom component.

In my experience, when you don't have an army of developers it's always better to keep the tables/grids slim and solve problems creatively around them than to build a supercharged table that in the end will never solver every future use case. I guess react-tables and react-form new concepts are aligned with this "philosophy".

The next problem you'll find the datagrid grouping is how do you group paged data and how to do you explain those differences between full data set and paged data set groupings to the user.

Comment: Expanding every row as its own drop-down, as in the demo to which you've linked, is not what the poster asked for.   He wants to group a number of rows by some common value.